# How to merge objects of array together if a condition match ? Javascirpt

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

how to merge objects of array together if a condition match. The condition from the array of object I need start time and end time to be merged together.

I have a array like this

```
  [
      {id: 909, room: "room1", name: "end", timestamp: '10:00'}, 
      {id: 908, room: "room1", name: "start", timestamp: '09:00'}, 
      {id: 907, room: "room1", name: "end", timestamp: '08:00'}, 
      {id: 906, room: "room1", name: "start", timestamp: '07:00'}, 
  ]
```

From the above array, if the next index from `name: "end"` is `name:start` then I want to pair them up together. The array to now look like this

```
    [
        {room: "room1", endTimestamp: '10:00', startTimetamp: '09:00'}, 
        {room: "room1", endTimestamp: '08:00', startTimetamp: '07:00'}, 
      
    ]
```

there might also be instance where array could start with `name:start` and doesn't have it's end time yet that would look like this

```
  [
      {id: 910, room: "room1", name: "start", timestamp: '11:00'}, 
      {id: 909, room: "room1", name: "end", timestamp: '10:00'}, 
      {id: 908, room: "room1", name: "start", timestamp: '09:00'}, 
      {id: 907, room: "room1", name: "end", timestamp: '08:00'}, 
      {id: 906, room: "room1", name: "start", timestamp: '07:00'}, 
  ]
```

In this case the array should look like this

```
    [
        { room: "room1", endTimestamp: null, startTimetamp: '11:00'},
        { room: "room1", endTimestamp: '10:00', startTimetamp: '09:00'}, 
        { room: "room1", endTimestamp: '08:00', startTimetamp: '07:00'}, 
    ]
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the condition of matching two rows together? I understand, that they have to have different "name" value. I assume they must have the same "room" value too.
But why are you matching id 906 with id 907? And not for example 906 with 909?
The objective is to match elements with adjacent **indexes** of with adjacent **id**?

Comment: And second question: which "id" should have the result row? The **id** of start or the **id** of end? Always the higher of them?

Comment: @PrzemysławNiemiec I have taken off the id, they are not needed when merged together. Yes they must have the same room. in this example there is only room1. but room1 can have multiple start/end time. the only way to tell start/end time belong together is if the next index from the obj that has `name : end` is obj that has `name: start`. This is the condition

Answer (score 1):

There are probably shorter anwers, but I want to show to the simplest to explain:

First, you have to create an result array:

```
const InputArray = [/*your array here*/];
const ResultArray = [];
```

Then you can loop through the array looking for "start" rows and creating a **ResultRow** for each **start row**:

```
for( let i=0 ; i < InputArray.length ; i++ ) {
    if( InputArray[i].name !== 'start' )
        continue;
  
    const ResultRow = {
        room: InputArray[i].room, 
        startTimetamp: InputArray[i].timestamp, 
        endTimetamp: null
    };

    // check previous index
    if( i-1 >= 0 ) 
        if( InputArray[i-1].name === 'end' )
            if( InputArray[i].room === InputArray[i-1].room )
                ResultRow.endTimestamp = InputArray[i-1].timestamp ;

    ResultArray.push(ResultRow);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer this didn't quite solve my problem, when there are mutiple rooms. if room01 has start time but no endtime. then you have room02 with start time but has a end time then this doesn't quite work

Comment: This code checks if the rooms are the same: `InputArray[i].room === InputArray[i-1].room`. I`m not sure if I understand you well. Can you give me an example array and expected output? :)